# Wordpress on IIS - Plugins were successfully installed but they don't show

Tags: wordpress, iis

I have installed WordPress on IIS 8.5 (Windows server 2012 R2) by installing PHP and MySQL without any problem. The WordPress website works normally and plugins (like any kind of sliders) installed with no error. but the installed plugin doesn't show on WordPress website.

-PHP have set on PHP Manager.

-Directory Browsing is enable.

-Full Permission granted on folders to : IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, windows current user.

-Various plugins have been tested: MetaSlider, LayerSlider, MasterSlider, NextGenGallery and so on.

Answer (score 0):

as you said that "MetaSlider, LayerSlider, MasterSlider, NextGenGallery" these plugins are not working. I made a test with the  MetaSlider plugin.

first thing you need to change in WordPress permalink setting.

make sure you use this setting in permalink:

[image]

then select the plugins and click on add new and installed the MetaSlider plugin.

and active that plugin.

add slide show using that and create a new page and added the slideshow.

[image]

[image]

after doing this publish the site and check the page by using preview.

[image]

if you still face some problem than clear the cache and the history of the browser and try to access the page again.